# Hide specific payment method based on total weight in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, unset, payment-method

In woocommerce I would like to hide a "Cash on delivery" payment method for a specific total weight.

For example if cart total weight is up to **15 kilos**, "Cash on delivery" payment method on checkout.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following simple code will hide "COD" payment method if cart total weight is up to **`15 Kg`**. 
I assume that the weight unit set in Woocommerce is **Kg** *(kilos)*.

The code:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_payment_gateways', 'hide_payment_gateways_based_on_weight', 11, 1 );
function hide_payment_gateways_based_on_weight( $available_gateways ) {
    if ( is_admin() ) return $available_gateways; // Only on frontend

    $total_weight = WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_weight();

    if( $total_weight >= 15 && isset($available_gateways['cod']) )
        unset($available_gateways['cod']); // unset 'cod'

    return $available_gateways;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and work.