# Disable all payment gateways except BACS based on geo-ip country in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, geolocation, payment-gateway

In Woocommerce, I am using the code made from [this answer thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49954740/disable-payment-gateways-based-on-user-country-geo-ip-in-woocommerce/49955799#49955799) which enables ALL payment gateways if the user's GEO IP is from an array of allowed countries. Here the allowed country code that I want is **"SE"** *(Sweden)*.

What I would like is to disable all payment gateways except BACS to become available if the GEO IP is outside of Sweden (the pre-defined allowed country).

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Yes, will do. Thank you very much for your help and for the updated version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code will disable all available payment gateways except BACS for non allowed GEO IP defined countries *(Here Sweden)*:

```
// Disabling payment gateways (except BACS) based on user IP geolocation country
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_payment_gateways', 'geo_country_based_available_payment_gateways', 90, 1 );
function geo_country_based_available_payment_gateways( $available_gateways ) {
    // Not in backend (admin)
    if( is_admin() ) 
        return $available_gateways;

    // ==> HERE define your country codes
    $allowed_country_codes = array('SE');

    // Get an instance of the WC_Geolocation object class
    $geolocation_instance = new WC_Geolocation();
    // Get user IP
    $user_ip_address = $geolocation_instance->get_ip_address();

    // Get geolocated user IP country code.
    $user_geolocation = $geolocation_instance->geolocate_ip( $user_ip_address );

    // Disable payment gateways (except BACS) for all countries except the allowed defined countries
    if ( ! in_array( $user_geolocation['country'], $allowed_country_codes ) ){
        $bacs_gateways              = $available_gateways['bacs'];
        $available_gateways         = array();
        $available_gateways['bacs'] = $bacs_gateways;
    }

    return $available_gateways;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Related: [Disable payment gateways based on user country geo-ip in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49954740/disable-payment-gateways-based-on-user-country-geo-ip-in-woocommerce/49955799#49955799)

Comment: Sorry if this is the wrong way of doing this, but I don't know how to "tag" someone. Would you perhaps know how to add the gravatar picture to the WooCommerce Product Reviews dashboard widget?

I made a question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52464394/gravatar-on-woocommerce-product-reviews

Comment: @bjornen Sorry I don't know about that.