# Disable WooCommerce payment gateway for guests and specific user roles

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, payment-gateway, user-roles

I have disabled the invoice payment mehtod for one of the user roles in my site ('customer') but now I need to add another user role ('business') to this rule and I can't figure out how to make it work. When I add the second role, the code stops working altogether and it ends up showing the gateway to all users.

Here's the code I'm using to disable the gateway:

I'm not very experienced with PHP so any help will be tremendously appreciated. 
If there's any chance you can correct my code to fit the use case, I would be very grateful.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_payment_gateways', 'payment_gateway_disable_private' );

 function payment_gateway_disable_private( $available_gateways ) {

    $user = wp_get_current_user();

    if ( isset( $available_gateways['igfw_invoice_gateway'] ) && !is_user_logged_in() || isset( $available_gateways['igfw_invoice_gateway'] ) && in_array('customer', $user->roles)  ) {
        unset( $available_gateways['igfw_invoice_gateway'] );
    }

   return $available_gateways;

}
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a mistake in your if statement *(also you can use `current_user_can()` function for user roles)* like:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_payment_gateways', 'payment_gateway_disable_private' );
function payment_gateway_disable_private( $available_gateways ) {
    if ( ( ! is_user_logged_in() || current_user_can('customer') || current_user_can('business') ) 
    && isset( $available_gateways['igfw_invoice_gateway'] ) ) {
        unset( $available_gateways['igfw_invoice_gateway'] );
    }
   return $available_gateways;
}
```

or with the `global $current_user;` and `array_intersect()` function:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_payment_gateways', 'payment_gateway_disable_private' );
function payment_gateway_disable_private( $available_gateways ) {
    global $current_user;

    // Here define your user roles
    $user_roles = array( 'customer', 'business' );

    if ( ( ! is_user_logged_in() || array_intersect( $current_user->roles, $user_roles ) ) 
    && isset( $available_gateways['igfw_invoice_gateway'] ) ) {
        unset( $available_gateways['igfw_invoice_gateway'] );
    }
   return $available_gateways;
}
```

It should better work now.